# Best way to integrate document scanner in my spring mvc web application

Tags: java, spring, twain

I want integrate document scanner in my spring mvc web application
I know we can use applet with twain library but it is deprecated in html 5 and dot support x64 architecture
There are same solution li aspire but it is not free

pls help me

Answer (score 1):

You are right, all the solutions are not free.

And on top of it all, we can't use Java applets because they're deprecated... and ActiveX is IE-only.

So, I created a library: [removed as I plan to release it again with proper doc] that acts like Google's WebUSB API.

What you need to do:

- Install Python 2.7.
- Navigate to webagent-scanner's root folder and run: `app.py`
- app.py will create a localhost web server w/ port 8087.
- Use Javascript in your web application to make a GET request to https://localhost:8087/scan
- The response is a base64 encoded string of JPEG image. You can now then use it however you want.

Comment: Thinkyou very mach for your response Spacemudd i will tray your solution and give you a feed back

Comment: @newcoder You should do `pip install twain` in cmd.

Comment: PS C:\Python27> pip install twain
Collecting twain
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twain (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for twain
PS C:\Python27>

Comment: @newcoder [I updated the package's README.md](https://github.com/spacemudd/webagent-scanner#installation). Try following the steps.

Comment: thinkyou for replay now server is running but when i sent ajax request i get ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in console pls advice

Comment: @newcoder Try navigating to `https://localhost:8083/multi-scan`, it works? Anyway, are you using IE? You must add the localhost.crt to your IE settings. `Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates -> Import` and choose the .crt that is being served by the web agent.

Comment: thinkyou now it tray to open scanner but showing blow error PS G:\webagent-scanner-master> python .\app.py
['CanoScan LiDE 120', 'WIA-CanoScan LiDE 120']
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET /multi-scan (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='https', host='localhost:8087', method='GET', uri='/multi-scan', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', 
Traceback (most recent call last):

    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File ".\app.py", line 40, in get
    images = multiScan()
  File ".\app.py", line 98, in multiScan

Comment: @newcoder Can you do 'git pull' again? Code was updated.

Comment: @newcoder I can see you have 2 scanners loaded. `['CanoScan LiDE 120', 'WIA-CanoScan LiDE 120']`. Do this... open app.py and go to line `90` and change `loadScanner.setScanner(devices[0])` to `loadScanner.setScanner(devices[1])`. Launch app.py and try again.

Comment: thinks now when i sent ajax request to /multi-scan scanner work fine but get this error in console : Unable to get the "images" property of a null or undefined reference

Comment: @newcoder That's Javascript and you will have to debug that on your own in your web app.